# How to pass a dynamic struct by reference to change his size and insert into it?

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
struct student_name {
    char first_name[50];
    char middle_name[50];
    char last_name[50];
};

struct student_information {
    struct student_name name;
}

void set_new_student(struct student_information **info, int *studCount) {
    (*studCount)++;
    *info = realloc(*info, *studCount * sizeof(struct student_information));

    printf("Enter the Student data:\n");
    printf("First name: "); scanf("%s",(*info)[(*studCount)].name.first_name);
    printf("Middle name: "); scanf("%s",(*info)[(*studCount)].name.middle_name);
    printf("Last name: "); scanf("%s",(*info)[(*studCount)].name.last_name);

    printf("%d\n",sizeof(*info));

     return;
}

int main() {
    struct student_information* student = NULL;
    int student_counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
      set_new_student(&student, &student_counter);
}
```

when I call this function from the main function with loop it working for the first 2 iterations but in the third one it gives me a run time error also the print state meant print 4 all the time and I think the size should change, isn't it?

Comment: What's the definition of `struct student_information`?

Comment: I edit it now sir.

Comment: @dbush 
it gives me a run time error when I try to add the second or third student not constant

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: *print 4 all the time and I think the size should change*  If `info` is of type `struct student_information **`, what type of variable is `*info`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing past the end of the array.

On the first call to `set_new_student` you increment `*studCount` from 0 to 1 and allocate an array with 1 element.  That element has index 0.  Then you write to array element `*studCount` which is 1, and one element past the end.  Writing past the end of allocated memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Subtract 1 from the counter value to get the appropriate index value:

```
printf("First name: "); scanf("%s",(*info)[*studCount - 1].name.first_name);
printf("Middle name: "); scanf("%s",(*info)[*studCount - 1].name.middle_name);
printf("Last name: "); scanf("%s",(*info)[*studCount - 1].name.last_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

dbush is correct about your first question.

In response to your second question, the sizeof operator only works on objects where the size is known at compile time.  When you dynamically allocate memory, as you are doing with realloc, there is no mechanism to save the amount of memory you allocated and feed it to the sizeof operator.  `*info` is a pointer anyway, so you are getting the size of a pointer.